# Tomcat 5.5 Deployment - Not Picking Up Class

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, war, web-deployment

I'm having a strange problem with one of my classes in an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project.  I compile the war, save it to /webapps, startup Tomcat, see the war deployed.  The only problem is that one of my classes (the one I use to query a PostgresSQL db) does not appear to be updating.  I see the file update in the WEB-INF directory of the deployed war but the code that is running is not the code in the class.  Namely it runs a SQL query that doesn't exist anywhere in class any longer - giving me a SQL error every time it's run.

Also, system.out.println statements in all my classes are showing up in the console except for this one class.

I'm using the Apache bundled with JUDDI (Tomcat 5.5).  This one has me seriously stumped.

Comment: ouaou, and you expect us to find the issue ?

Comment: Well, that would be ideal, but even shots in the dark would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: bounce the server.  It sounds like an older version of the .class file is cached, so your new one isn't being loaded.

UPDATE: Since you've bounced the server, I'd say you should simplify the problem by taking out things that are unnecessary until you can make it work - because this *does* work.

*Don't use Eclipse*.  Build, package, and deploy your WAR by hand to Tomcat outside of Eclipse.  Start Tomcat in a shell using the startup script.  See if it picks up your new class.